# How many transformations does Naruto have?

Tags: naruto

In Shounen, transformations are an important part of the character developpment as he often gets stronger through them.

What are Naruto's different transformations ?

Answer (score 1):

Naruto has like 2 or 5 transformations depending on how you count it:

> Uncontrolled Jinchurichi mode
>
> Controlled Jinchurichi mode, where he steals Chakra from Kurama
>
> Naruto and Kurama in Sync, transform together.
>
> Sage mode
>
> Sage, Jinchurichi Mode.

You can count it as two if you consider All Jinchurichi transformation as one and Sage transformations as other.